# Connect to postgresql database via MATLAB error

Tags: database, postgresql, matlab, jdbc, database-connection

I am trying to connect my Postgres database in MATLAB and it is throwing me an error stating

`"'JDBC Driver Error: org.postgresql.Driver. Driver Not Found/Loaded.'"`

Here's my connection method that i have used.

```
conn = database('postgres','username','password','org.postgresql.Driver', 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres=postgres');
```

after that it throws me the error.

I have looked at forums and they told me to add the postgres jar files to the MATLAB directory toolkit textfile, such as below.

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\pgJDBC\postgresql-8.4.702.jdbc3.jar 
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\pgJDBC\postgresql-8.4.702.jdbc4.jar
```

I don't know where else I am going wrong. Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add jar file with JDBC driver to your dynamic java class path before connecting to database. I believe you can add only one file depending on your requirements. Check the versions difference [here](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html).

To avoid warning if a jar file already in the path add some check:

```
%# add class path (if not in the class path)
p = 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\pgJDBC\postgresql-8.4.702.jdbc3.jar';
if ~ismember(p,javaclasspath)
    javaaddpath(p)
end
```

Comment: It works. But somehow i can't seem to query an information from the database into MATLAB. Here's the code that i am trying to use : `e = exec(conn,'SELECT *FROM cath_2');
e = fetch(e);`. This is the error, `??? Undefined function or method 'fetch' for input arguments of type 'struct'.`

Comment: How about if you use another variable to return fetch result? `rs = fetch(e);` I usually just do `rs = fetch(exec(conn, qry));`. If it does not work try to use another JDBC driver.

Comment: `exec` actually returns a cursor object, not a structure. Are you using the Database Toolbox?

Comment: My apologies, i wrote the url connection wrong. It's fixed now. I got another problem if you dont mind helping me. I am trying to query a table into MATLAB such as this, `rs = fetch(exec(conn, 'SELECT * FROM cath_2'));`, and it somehow doesnt recognise the table in the database eventhough it does exists. It states `'Invalid Cursor: ERROR: relation "cath_2" does not exist`.

Comment: Try query `'show tables'`. It should return list of tables in your database. Maybe you connected to a wrong database?

Comment: My apologies, You're right. I had the wrong port number. I manage to query the information. How do i then view the table?

Comment: No worries. I just had to include `rs.Data` in the command window to display the output of the table fields. Thank you very much for your help. :)