# Importing a Database to MATLAB error

Tags: connection, database-connection, fetch, matlab

I am trying to import tables to my MATLAB workspace and it keeps throwing me an error, `"Undefined function or method 'fetch' for input arguments of type 'struct'.`"

This is my code that i am trying to execute:

```
dyn_conformer = exec(conn, 'SELECT * FROM dyn_conformer'); 
rs =fetch(dyn_conformer);
```

When i opened the object in the workspace, it stated that it was `"Invalid or closed connection"`.
However, previously i manage to import other tables and it seemed to execute perfectly (they are stored as a cursor object). All of a sudden, its throwing an error for other tables that i am trying to import.

I am connected to the datatabase, `conn = database('postgres','username','password','org.postgresql.Driver','jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/postgres');`.

Comment: In your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855781/connect-to-postgresql-database-via-matlab-error) you stated that you had the same error when you made a mistake in connection url. Did you check carefully that everything is correct now? Before running `exec` check connection with `isconnection` function.

Comment: I managed to fix the problem. Apparently from the function you gave me in my previous question, that i have to check if the postgresql driver does exist, add it to the classpath and then i had to run my connection function again to connect to the database. I was wondering, if there's some kind of method in which it allows me to bypass myself from running the same code everytime if i want to access my database from MATLAB ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to check for existing of connection variable and that it is the properly established connection before running `exec`. You can do it like this:

```
if ~exist('conn','var') || ~isconnection(conn)
    conn = database('postgres','username','password','org.postgresql.Driver',...
           'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/postgres');
else
    dyn_conformer = exec(conn, 'SELECT * FROM dyn_conformer'); 
    rs =fetch(dyn_conformer);
end
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to check whether the connection is established. Does this mean that i have to do a new connection everytime i open MATLAB, since running an existing connection from a saved workspace doesnt seem to work. How bout this code you gave me `p = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\pgJDBC\postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar';
if ~any(ismember(javaclasspath,p))
    javaaddpath(p)
end`, can this be written in a variable so that it can be executed each time i open MATLAB?

Comment: Yes, you have to establish connection every time you open MATLAB, restart database server, ... cannot list all possible circumstances. It's a MATLAB session connected to a database. So I think it's useless to save the database variable. Better write a function without arguments, but with all the parameters inside. Then you can just call your function, like `conn=connect_to_my_db();` and grab the data you need. I also have second function for the data, like this: `function data=get_db_data(conn,sql) 
if isconnection(conn),rs=fetch(exec(conn,sql));data=get(rs,'Data');end` Very handy.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for the help. Will get back to you if i have any problems.