# Matlab database connection: Undefined function or method 'fetch' for input arguments of type 'struct'

Tags: database, matlab, database-connection, fetch

I have a strange error that comes when my database connection is established and then its throughs out this error when executing `e=fetch(e)` that  `Undefined function or method 'fetch' for input arguments of type 'struct'`. I am calling another function to manipulate on the extracted data

```
Function loadlib(Pin,con_sem)
load(Pin,con_sem);
end
```

But now when I run the connection command is separate m file like this

```
clear;
con_sem = database('OptProgramSemiLib','root','*********');
e=exec(con_sem,['SELECT *FROM Cond WHERE Type LIKE ''MO'' ']); (here it gives message in debug mode' invalid or closed connection)
e=fetch(e);
e.Data
close(con_sem);
```

then it doesnt gives me this error. I also had this problem when I tried accessing database from another account(with administrator rights).
Any sugestions please. Where I am going wrong.

Comment: We need more info about what calls are made when it fails. It is less helpful to show the one that succeeds...

Comment: loadlib function is called which then invokes load(Pin,con_sem) to pass the data from the database. Using debug option it goes fine till the fetch command after then it gives an error. it gives this msg in debug mode 'Invalid or close connection'

Comment: Is `load` the standard matlab function that loads data from a matfile?

Comment: no ..i just shorted the name to load, actually it is loadlib.Its not built in function.

Comment: I mean in this line: `load(Pin,con_sem);` It looks like you're trying to load a database connection object from a file. Please edit your code to show *exactly what you are doing*

Comment: the problem solved by itself..I dont know may there was some bug. But I launched querybuilder to see the driver that I am using and I eventually ended up changing the drivers(Define OBDC Data source)and now it gives me this error 'Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.' How can I revert back.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot load connection object. Once you close the connection or the MATLAB session after you established connection, the connection to database is lost. You have to connect to the database again.

Better save m-file with a script or function to establish connection. You can always check if the connection object is valid with [ISCONNECTION](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/database/ug/isconnection.html) function.

Also see my answer and a follow-up comment to [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9155260/163080).