# matlab error when connecting to postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, matlab

I'm trying to connec to a PostgreSQL database with following command:

```matlab
connection = database( ...
        options.getDatabaseName(), ...
        options.getUsername(), ...
        options.getPassword(), ...
        "org.postgresql.Driver", ...
        "jdbc:postgresql://" + options.getHostname() + ":" + options.getPort() + "/" + options.getDatabaseName() ...
        );
```

It returns me following error:

```
Error using database (line 59)
Unmatched parameter name 'org.postgresql.Driver' must be a string scalar or character vector that can represent a field name.
```

I've seen other questions about that, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855781/connect-to-postgresql-database-via-matlab-error) but the error message is different.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sure looks like you're doing it right. The `database()` signature is kind of wonky. What happens if you use `char` arrays (single-quoted) instead of `string` arrays (double-quoted) in your arguments?

Comment: Also make sure that the first three `optiosn.getDatabaseName()` etc. arguments are not returning empty; that might foul up `database()`'s signature parsing heuristics.

Comment: BTW, what version of Matlab, and what OS are you running on? I could pull up the source and look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution by myself, and it's tricky (maybe related to a bug in my opinion).

In order to test the database connection I've created first a connection with the Database explorer. It worked, and I saved this connection using the same name of the database.

When I use the `database` command, by inspecting it source code I've seen that the first thing that it does it to check if there's an existing data source with that name and, if not, it search for the database. The problem was that since my connection had the same database name, `database` supposed that I wanted to use the data source command version instead of the database. It tried to use this command:

```
conn = database(datasource,username,password)
```

instead of this one:

```
conn = database(databasename,username,password,driver,url)
```

since `wtrade` is both name of the database and of the data source. In that case the fourth argument, `driver`, must be a parameter name, like `"Vendor"` of `"PortNumber"`, as per Matlab documentation, so since the driver string does not match a parameter name, I had the error.

I've removed the datasource with the same name of the database and everything started to work.

I've notified this to MathWorks, since in my opinion there should be no problem if a database has the same name of a datasource, since the signature are different, so `database` command should handle also this case.